# AutoCompleteTextView Events to continuously create new adapter

Tags: android, json, listview, autocompletetextview

I am working on autocompleteTextView feature in android. I am trying to give option while the user types, the options are actually coming from a web API (json format).My doubt is:
say, user starts typing,when user types 3 characters, i need to ping the webAPI , get all the options it sends me. i create the ArrayList Adapter. Now i want to continue filtering the options depending on the user input.I want to continously send the input to webAPI and get JSON data, create another adapter and refresh autocomplete option for user.

I am not getting the event i need to capture to do this successfully?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: post the code where you retrieve the json and bind the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

> create ArrayListAdapter

You should not create new adapter over and over again but update the dataset it servers and notify the adapter about the change by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thank you, Let me try notifyDataSetChange().